# Using an exported function in the same file it's exported

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to find out if it's okay (not bad practice) to use an exported function in the same file it's being exported and also the file it's being imported? I'm using a webpack/babel setup.

Example case:

```
File1.js (the file that exports the function):
  export default myFunction(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    // some code
  }

  window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('some-element').addEventListener('change', e => myFunction(e));
  }

File2.js:
  import myFunction from './File1';

  window.onload = () => {
    document.getElementById('some-element').addEventListener('change', e => myFunction(e));
  }
```

Comment: Side note: `.addEventListener(e => myFunction(e))` could just be `.addEventListener(myFunction)`. No need for the extra wrapping arrow function.

Comment: Side note 2: The `load` event happens *very* late in the page load process. In general, better to just put your `script` tag(s) at the very end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and have them look for the element immediately rather than waiting. All elements defined by the HTML before the `script` tag are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Side note 3: `export default myFunction(e) {` is a syntax error. You either want `export default function myFunction(e) { /*...*/ }` or `export default const myFunction = e => { /*...*/ };` or `export default const myFunction = function(e) { /*...*/ };`

Comment: Re my first side note, I should add: ...unless you've done that specifically so that both handlers get added even though you're using the same element and same function. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely fine to use the function both in its own module and in other modules that import it.